# Matlab using accumarray with cell array

Tags: mysql, arrays, matlab, accumarray

I am quite new to Matlab, but I have some experience with other programming languages. I have a very large table imported from MySQL in Matlab. It is given as cell array that looks something like this:

```
 date   key     sales    weight  name
 12/11  101     1200     20      blue
 12/11  178     1200     70      purple
 13/11  209     1300     15      purple
 12/11  101     1200     10      blue
 14/11  678     1200     10      yellow
 12/11  340     1500     30      green
 17/11  178     1900     50      purple
```

And I want the output to be this:

```
 key     sales    weight  name
 101     2400     30      blue
 178     3100     120     purple
 209     1300     15      purple
 678     1200     10      yellow
 340     1500     30      green
```

So I would like to combine the rows which have the same number in the column 'key'. Meanwhile I would like to sum the column 'sales' and 'weight' and keep the column 'name' (each 'key' has the same 'name', but each 'name' can have multiple 'keys')

I know this is possible with a for loop, but as I am having to manipulate a lot of tables in similar but different ways this is computational intensive.

I have read in similar problems this can be solved using accumarray, but can this be done with accumarray with a sub as cell array? And how would that look like?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how exactly your cell array is stored? Does it have headings? Is the entire `key` column one array, `sales` one array etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one method using `accumarray`, however it might be worth your while to consider the new [table](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/09/10/introduction-to-the-new-matlab-data-types-in-r2013b/) data structure instead of a cell matrix (I'm sure you can easily convert to it)

```
T = {  101     1200     20      'blue'
       178     1200     70      'purple'
       209     1300     15      'purple'
       101     1200     10      'blue'
       678     1200     10      'yellow'
       340     1500     30      'green'
       178     1900     50      'purple'};

[u, ind, x] = unique([T{:,1}])

key = T(ind,1)
sales = accumarray(x', [T{:,2}])
weight = accumarray(x', [T{:,3}])
name = T(ind,4)

[key, num2cell(sales), num2cell(weight), name]
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you. I will have a look at the new table and categorical array that Matlab introduced!

Answer (score 2):

```
x={ '12/11'  101     1200     20      'blue'
 '12/11'  178     1200     70      'purple'
 '13/11'  209     1300     15      'purple'
 '12/11'  101     1200     10      'blue'
 '14/11'  678     1200     10      'yellow'
 '12/11'  340     1500     30      'green'
 '17/11'  178     1900     50      'purple'};

[~,b,c]=unique([x{:,2}]);
y=[x(b,2),...
    num2cell(sparse(1,c,[x{:,3}]))',...
    num2cell(sparse(1,c,[x{:,4}]))',...
    x(b,[5])];
```

`unique` is used to get the indices of duplicate keys. `sparse` is used to get the sum.

Comment: I think you mean `y=[x(b,2), num2cell(sparse(1,c,[x{:,3}]))', num2cell(sparse(1,c,[x{:,4}]))',  x(b,[5])]`? Why does `sparse` sum btw?

Comment: @Dan: You are right, I summed only the sales, not the weight. Check `sparse([1,1],[1,1],[2,3])` to understand how `sparse` can be used to calculate a sum.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand it. I think it might be worth adding an explanation to your answer.

Comment: If you assign two values to the same index, `sparse` uses the sum. I think user3193435 should use your answer, `accumarray` it's propably easier to understand.

Comment: I tested it on my table and it worked! Thank you a lot.